# Merge Pandas Dataframes (ie: Orders and Inventory), then re-adjust Inventory

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stringio

I have an order list with a separate inventory system (Google Sheets).  Using Pandas, I'm trying to merge the two for an efficient "pick list" and have had some mild success.  However, in testing (adding multiple quantities for an order, having multiple orders with the same item/SKU type) it starts breaking down.

```
orders = "orderNumber,SKU,Quantity\r\n11111,GreenSneakers,2\r\n11111,Brown_Handbag,1\r\n22222,GreenSneakers,1\r\n33333,Blue_Handbag,1"
str_orders = StringIO(orders, newline='\n')
df_orders = pd.read_csv(str_orders, sep=",")

inventory = "SKU,Location\r\nGreenSneakers,DA13A\r\nGreenSneakers,DA13A\r\nRed_Handbag,DA12A\r\nGreenSneakers,DB34C\r\nGreenSneakers,DB33C\r\n"
str_inventory = StringIO(inventory, newline='\n')
df_inventory = pd.read_csv(str_inventory, sep=",")
df_inventory = df_inventory.sort_values(by='Location', ascending=False)

df_pList = df_orders.merge(df_inventory.drop_duplicates(subset=['SKU']), on='SKU', how='left')
print(df_pList)
```

pseudo desired output:

```
'
orderNumber, SKU, Quantity, Location
11111, GreenSneakers, 1, DB34C
11111, GreenSneakers, 1, DB33C
11111, Brown_Handbag, 1, NA
22222, GreenSneakers, 1, DA13A
33333, Blue_Handbag, 1, NA

'
```

Is Merge even a way to solve this type of a problem?  Trying to stay away from looping if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below makes three dataframes.

`df_pickList` is what you were asking to make

`copy_inventory` contains what inventory would be if you pick everything (in case you want to just write the DataFrame out to overwrite your inventory file)  You could elect to not make the copy and use your `df_inventory` directly, but especially in beta its handy to make a copy for manipulation.

`df_outOfStock` is a handy bucket to catch things you don't have in inventory.  Cross check against current orders to see what you need to get on order

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import copy

orders = """orderNumber,SKU,Quantity
11111,GreenSneakers,2
11111,Brown_Handbag,1
22222,GreenSneakers,1
33333,Blue_Handbag,1
"""
str_orders = StringIO(orders, newline='\n')
df_orders = pd.read_csv(str_orders, sep=",")

inventory = """SKU,Location
GreenSneakers,DA13A
GreenSneakers,DA13A
Red_Handbag,DA12A
GreenSneakers,DB34C
GreenSneakers,DB33C
"""
str_inventory = StringIO(inventory, newline='\n')
df_inventory = pd.read_csv(str_inventory, sep=",")
df_inventory = df_inventory.sort_values(by='Location', ascending=False)

df_outOfStock = pd.DataFrame() #placeholder to report a lack of stock
df_pickList = pd.DataFrame() #placeholder to make pick list
copy_inventory = copy.deepcopy(df_inventory) #make a copy of inventory to decimate

for orderIndex, orderLineItem in df_orders.iterrows():
    for repeat in range(orderLineItem["Quantity"]): #since inventory location is 1 row per item, we need to do that many picks per order line item
        availableInventory = copy_inventory.loc[copy_inventory.loc[:,"SKU"] == orderLineItem["SKU"], :]
        if len(availableInventory) == 0:
            #Failed to find any SKU to pull
            df_outOfStock = df_outOfStock.append(orderLineItem, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            pickRow = {"orderNumber": orderLineItem["orderNumber"],
                       "SKU": orderLineItem["SKU"],
                       "Quantity": 1,
                       "Location": availableInventory.iloc[0]["Location"]}
            df_pickList = df_pickList.append(pickRow, ignore_index=True)
            copy_inventory.drop(index = availableInventory.index[0], inplace=True)
```

Thanks, this was a fun little exercise compared to dealing with non-integer quantities (i.e. feet of angle iron)

***(Original wrong answer below)***

I would recommend concatenating the rows into a single table (not merging and/or overwriting values), then using group by to allow the aggregation of values.

As a primer, I would start with these two links on putting your data together:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby

Comment: At work I went through your question and thought I had a good grasp on what you were attempting to accomplish, but now that I'm back home I think I was mistaken.  could you please update your original question to include the desired output from the sample code.  I'd comment on your question to ask you, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on anything except my answer.

Comment: Absolutely I can.  I'm not by my main computer at the moment, so hopefully the 'pseudo output' helps

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid looping?  I'll need to mull this over a bit to come up with a solution that doesn't loop.  Until then I recommend you breakdown your code to learn what is happening. `df_inventory.drop_duplicates(subset=['SKU'])` happens FIRST in you big one-liner.  To help understand break it up into two lines: `temp = df_inventory.drop_duplicates(subset=['SKU'])` and `df_pList = df_orders.merge(temp, on='SKU', how='left')`.  Then you can print `temp` to see what `merge` is trying to work with.

Comment: Thank you, I see drop_duplicates is not what I'm looking for.  Is there a way to merge the lists and have the left (order list) join each subsequent inventory match without duplicating?

Comment: With looping I thought it might slow down with the thousands of inventory lines.  I could be ignorant here too.

Comment: Looping will probably be quicker than you think, but the real benefit will be that you can live drop the index of the item assigned to be picked for an order from the `df_inventory` within the loop.  Then your final inventory table after processing will represent actual inventory remaining after your pick operations.  Right now you are generating the pick list and you will later need to update your inventory.  I'm in the middle of an ERP implementation with 20k+ items and the discussions on how and when inventory should be updated is serious, so weigh the pros and cons.